# How to integrate MSpec with MS Build?

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, bdd, mspec

Few days ago I watched a [BDD screencast](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/kona-3/) by [Rob Conery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/). In the video he showed how to use [MSpec](http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2008/09/02/mspec-v0-2.aspx), so I downloaded it and played with the bits. What I want now is to integrate [MSpec](http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2008/09/02/mspec-v0-2.aspx) with MS Build, but I don't know how... I use TFS team build as my CI server - Can you help me to integrate [MSpec](http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2008/09/02/mspec-v0-2.aspx) with MSBuild?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment the easiest way is to just Exec it.

```
 <Target Name="RunSpecs">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MSpecCommand>
        lib\machine\specifications\Machine.Specifications.ConsoleRunner.exe $(AdditionalSettings) path\to\your\project\bin\Debug\Your.Project.Specs.dll path\to\your\other\project\bin\Debug\Your.Other.Project.dll 
      </MSpecCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running Specs with this command: $(MSpecCommand)"/>
    <Exec Command="$(MSpecCommand)" />
  </Target>
```

Edit: Notice Additional Settings, you can call into the target like this:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="yourmsbuild.msbuild" Targets="RunSpecs" Properties="AdditionalSettings=-s -t -i &quot;web&quot; --html Specs\Specs.html"/>
```

If you pass --teamcity as an argument it outputs teamcity specific log data so TeamCity will track your tests.

```
Machine.Specifications
Copyright (C) 2007, 2008

Usage: mspec-runner.exe [options] <assemblies>
Options:
  -i, --include     Executes all specifications in contexts with these comma delimited tags. Ex. -i "foo,bar,foo_bar"
  -x, --exclude     Exclude specifications in contexts with these comma delimited tags. Ex. -x "foo,bar,foo_bar"
  -t, --timeinfo    Shows time-related information in HTML output
  -s, --silent      Suppress console output
  --teamcity        Reporting for TeamCity CI integration.
  --html <PATH>     Outputs an HTML file(s) to path, one-per-assembly w/ index.html (if directory, otherwise all are in
one file)
  -h, --help        Shows this help message
```

Comment: Note that when you are doing this with NAnt use arg line="assembly1 assembly2" not arg value (otherwise you will get a nice error that is very non-obvious)