# TeamCity & MSpec with sln2008 runner?

Tags: teamcity, mspec

I'm currently using the sln2008 runner.  Is there a way to configure TeamCity to execute MSpec tests without switching to a NAnt or MSBuild runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done it, but you could probably add a post build Exec task that just shelled out to mspec.exe. Just throw the code from my answer linked to above ([How to integrate MSpec with MS Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938347/how-to-integrate-mspec-with-ms-build)) in your specs csproj and add DependsOnTargets="RunSpecs" to your AfterBuild target:

```
  <Target Name="RunSpecs">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MSpecCommand>
        lib\machine\specifications\Machine.Specifications.ConsoleRunner.exe $(AdditionalSettings) path\to\your\project\bin\Debug\Your.Project.Specs.dll path\to\your\other\project\bin\Debug\Your.Other.Project.dll 
      </MSpecCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running Specs with this command: $(MSpecCommand)"/>
    <Exec Command="$(MSpecCommand)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="RunSpecs">
  </Target>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks Aaron!  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works out. That said, unless you have a very good reason for sticking to the sln2008 runner I'd toss that goal aside and use msbuild or rake (I *much* prefer rake).

Comment: What would be the advantage of using msbuild or rake and not the sln2008 runner?

Comment: @DavidS simply the amount of flexibility it gives you and how easy it is to get the build to do exactly what you want. The above snippet I guessed at would only be a few lines in rake. For msbuild it's just nice to have a root msbuild so you can attach tasks that are global to the entire repository (such as generating an AssemblyInfo.cs before any csproj builds). I'd still prefer rake.

Answer (score 1):

You may use msbuild runner. Please see [How to integrate MSpec with MS Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938347/how-to-integrate-mspec-with-ms-build) for description on how to integrate msbuild and mspec

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I came across that answer as well.  I was hoping to do it using the sln2008 runner.