# MSpec Test Adapter with TFS

Tags: mspec

Has anyone successfully used the MSpec Test Adapter with TFS? If yes, can you please shed some light on how I would go on about doing this?

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938347/how-to-integrate-mspec-with-ms-build) post but it uses the console runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research and trial and error, I finally figured how to make this work. It's actually pretty easy.

1. Install the MSpec Test Adapter on the build server.
2. Download the MSpec Test Adapter and change the file type to .zip
3. Extract the files to a folder on your build server.
4. Point the "Version control path to custom assemblies" to the files in step 3 above. *Note: You can access the window to do this from Visual Studio by clicking Build > Manage Build Controllers > and selecting the controller.
5. Ensure in the build definition, you select Visual Studio Test Runner. This can be accessed from the test definition > Process tab > Test > Automated tests > Test source

When you run your build, you should see your tests run.